# how to pass a std::bind object to a function

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to pass a bind function to another function but i am getting error that there is no conversion available-

```
cannot convert argument 2 from 'std::_Bind<true,std::string,std::string (__cdecl *const )(std::string,std::string),std::string &,std::_Ph<2> &>' to 'std::function<std::string (std::string)> &'
```

The function:

```
std::string keyFormatter(std::string sKeyFormat, std::string skey)
{
    boost::replace_all(sKeyFormat, "$ID$", skey);
    return sKeyFormat;
}
```

The usage is like -

```
auto fun = std::bind(&keyFormatter, sKeyFormat, std::placeholders::_2);
client(sTopic, fun);
```

The client function looks like-

```
void client(std::function<std::string(std::string)> keyConverter)
{
    // do something.
}
```

Comment: Are you sure these are the real prototypes of your function? Your `keyFormatter` looks suspicious if `sKeyFormat` is not a reference, plus `client` accepts only one parameter.

Comment: Use lambda instead of `std::bind`

Comment: client accepts one parameter but thats a function pointer taking one string and returning one string thats why i am binding keyFormatter function's first param with sKeyFormat.

Comment: I was using lambda before but i cant use lambda since i need to deploy my code on linux and gcc version i have doesn't support lambdas though it does support std::bind and std::function

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using the wrong `placeholders`, you need `_1`:

```
auto fun = std::bind(&keyFormatter, sKeyFormat, std::placeholders::_1);
```

The number of the placeholder is not here to match the position of the args, but rather to choose which arguments to send to the original function in which position:

```
void f (int, int);

auto f1 = std::bind(&f, 1, std::placeholders::_1);
f1(2); // call f(1, 2);
auto f2 = std::bind(&f, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_1);
f2(3, 4); // call f(4, 3);
auto f3 = std::bind(&f, std::placeholders::_2, 4);
f3(2, 5); // call f(5, 4);
```

See [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), especially the examples at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Your client function looks like it's incomplete. You probably want the following:

```
void client(const std::string &, std::function<std::string(std::string)> keyConverter);
```

Also, the placeholder should be `std::placeholders::_1`.

A complete example would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

std::string keyFormatter(std::string sKeyFormat, std::string skey) {
    return sKeyFormat;
}

void client(std::string, std::function<std::string(std::string)> keyConverter) {
    // do something.
}


int main() {
    auto sKeyFormat = std::string("test");
    auto sTopic = std::string("test");
    auto fun = std::bind(&keyFormatter, sKeyFormat, std::placeholders::_1);
    client(sTopic, fun);
}
```